# Endless loop created if scanner receives something other than an int

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

In this java Method, the point is for scanner to receive an int between the min and the max values. If an **int** is received that is outside those bounds, the program correctly outputs "Invalid input". However if something like "g" or "h" or something other than an int is entered, an endless loop is created.

I tried to reinitialize Scanner in multiple locations in the code but it looks like when something other than an int is entered from a System.in, it just flies right by scanner again and keeps the loop going. Any Thoughts

```
public static int promptInt(int min, int max) {
    while (false != true) {
        int b = 0;
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Choose a value between " + min + " and " + max + ": ");
        if (scnr.hasNext()) {
            if (scnr.hasNextInt()) {
                b = scnr.nextInt();
                if (b <= max) {
                    return b;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Invalid Value");
                }
            }
            else if (scnr.hasNextInt() == false) {
                System.out.println("Not an Int");

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to read what the user has entered to start checking if the **next** token is an int: `scanner.next()` (yes, vowels matter, too). Otherwise, you keep testing if the **current** token is an int, and it's not an int, so you check once again, and it's still not an int, and again, and again, and again.

Comment: This is because in the else if you don’t actually call scanner.next() which means it will continue to trigger “if(scnr.hasNext())”

Comment: @JBNizet beat me to it :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per some comments above, a scnr.next() was needed otherwise it was continuing to check the first scanner that was initialized. Here is the revised code which now functions.

```
public static int promptInt(int min, int max) {
    Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (false != true) {
        int b = 0;
        System.out.print("Choose a number between " + min + " and " + max + ": ");
        if (scnr.hasNext()) {
            if (scnr.hasNextInt() == false) {
                System.out.println("Invalid value.");
                //the scnr.next was needed here
                scnr.next();
            }
            else {
                b = scnr.nextInt();
                if (b <= max) {
                    return b;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Invalid value.");
                }  
            }
        }
    }
}
```